# Dynamic Graphic with a goniometric circumference, angle and tangent

Tags: graphics, front-end, geometry, gui-construction

I would like to make a circle with radius 1 with axeses showed.

I would like to dynamically select a point on the circle, draw a line from that point to the center and draw the tangent line to that point.

Should I use a `ParametricPlot[]` in some way?

Is it possible to make that, dynamic moving the point with the mouse or a slider is needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This version is virtually identical to **J.M.'s** fine answer. It uses `Manipulate` rather than `DynamicModule`.

### Update

Edited as per suggestion from **Michael E2** to use `TrackingFunction` which eliminates the use of `Dynamic` entirely (neglecting the fact that the first argument of `Manipulate` is internally wrapped in a `Dynamic`).

A locator with the point initialized to lie on the circle at a 45 degree angle is used as the `Manipulator` control. Further the position of the point is constrained to lie on the circle using `TrackingFunction`.

```
Manipulate[

 Graphics[{
   {Blue, Circle[]},
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]},
   {Red, InfiniteLine[pt, Cross[pt]]}
   },
  Axes -> True,
  PlotRange -> 3/2
  ],

 {{pt, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> ((pt = Normalize[#]) &)}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If I was going to use `Manipulate`, I would take advantage of its features, like automatic construction of `Locator` controls and `TrackingFunction`: `Manipulate[Graphics[{{Blue, Circle[]}, {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]}, {Red, InfiniteLine[pt, Cross[pt]]}}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3/2], {{pt, {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> ((pt = Normalize[#]) &)}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Good suggestion (I have been fairly ignorant of `TrackingFunction`). Modified answer as per your suggestion.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Perfect, thank you. If I would like also to draw segment from the point to the axes, what should I add?

Comment: @Ale1794 Look up `Line` and `Part`, e.g. `pt[[1]]` and `pt[[2]]`.

Comment: @Ale1794 Add these lines to the list enclosed by `Graphics`. `{RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0], Line[{{pt[[1]], 0}, pt}]},
{Magenta, Line[{{0, pt[[2]]}, pt}]}`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple version:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 1}/Sqrt[2]}, 
              LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = Normalize[#]) &], 
                          Graphics[{{Blue, Circle[]},
                                    {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[pt]}]},
                                    {Red, InfiniteLine[Dynamic[pt], Dynamic[Cross[pt]]]}},
                                   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 3/2]]]
```

[image: circle and tangent]

I'll leave the fancy styling up to you.